# How to redirect from a view in kohana

Tags: php, redirect, kohana

I have a function called action_reg_user which insert data into the database. I tried doing the usual:

```
header('Location:page/param1/param2');
```

But it doesn't work

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $pword = md5($_POST['pword']);
    print_r($_POST);

?>
<a href="reg_user/<?php echo $username; ?>/<?php echo $pword; ?>">Continue Registration</a> 

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kohana doesn't generate the request headers until the final page is ready to go back to the browser. If you look in `application/bootstrap.php`, you'll see this near the very bottom:

```
echo Request::instance()
    ->execute()
    ->send_headers()
    ->response;
```

So what you'll want to do is get to the Request object and ask it to do the redirect for you. Usually, **this should be done in your controller**, not your view. In the controller, you can do `$this->request->redirect('kohana/path')`. If you insist on doing it in the view, you want `Request::current()->redirect('kohana/path')` to redirect the currently executing request in the hierarchical chain.

Be careful and notice those are NOT using `URL::base` in the path- `Request::redirect` handles that, so you just need to specify the controller/action/parameters.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the redirection should be done in controller

Comment: Another +1 for pointing that it should be done in the controller. @leyasu Sawada you should read more about the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
<?php
$this->request->redirect('url/to/redirect/');
```

Outside actions you can use this code

```
<?php
Request::initial()->redirect('url');
```

Comment: In my opinion, things like this don't belong in the view.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is tagged Kohana, I assume you are using it.

Kohana is a so called MVC framework. A view should not contain things like redirects and checking `$_POST` values. It should not contain major logic at all. Views are just meant for *presentation*.

You should place your redirect in you controller. That is also the place where you should check the `$_POST` values, and validate them. From the controller, you can pass the $_POST values on to the view.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see on your question i assume you are using the header function after you have already output some content.

header() can only be used before any form of output is sent back to the user.

Try placing the header on top before you do the print_r

```
<?php  
if(!empty($_POST)){
     $username = $_POST['uname'];
     $pword = md5($_POST['pword']);
     action_reg_user($username,$pword);
     if (/* data saved */){
        header('Location: page/param1/param2');  
        exit;
     }
}
?>
```

and once you set the redirect no other code should run.

I hope this is what you are trying to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP `header("Location: ..");` only accepts absolute full URL so simple passing `page/param1/param2` won't work.

You need:

```
header("Location:" . url::base() . "page/param1/param2");
```

Or even better:

```
url::redirect('page/param1/param2');
```

Comment: header can take a relative path